# What should I do if I cannot find the right community for my question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, meta, off-topic

I asked my question here: [1st post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52590150/1555615)

Then I got feedback that my question was **off-topic** (unrelated to the community), with 2-closing votes, without any suggestion about which is the right community for it.

Then I asked the same question in the next community I considered related: [2nd post](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/32155/20704)

Again my question was closed as **off-topic** (unrelated to the community), and no one proposed which is the right community.

**My question is:** what should be my **next step**, instead of hopping from one community to another?

I thought of Area 51 and creating a new community (e.g., "File Formats"), but I am not sure whether this should really be the next step.

I am also not sure whether Meta is for questions like: "Which community does my question fit to", or "Feature-request: create community with name: 'File formats'".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're unsure where to ask a question, you can always ask "Where do I ask a question about xxxxx?" here, on Meta Stack Exchange, and tag it with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

Answer (score -1):

I've seen the behavior especially on topics that are not frequented often. Here's my personal recommendation that serves me well.

1. **Post** to the correct category on the community of your choice.
2. **Monitor the posting** and add in answers/comments to clarify your issue.
3. **Don't be turned off** by off topic answers. Sometimes they are spot on. You just have to get their point of view.
4. **Post to other communities** if you cannot get a clear answer.
5. **Have a community of like minded people** whom you know to ask the same questions too. And if you get an answer there, be sure to answer your own post so someone in the future can be helped by it as well!

Comment: "Post to other communities" -> Bear in mind that cross-posting isn't allowed on [se], so maybe you would like to elaborate this point.

Comment: I don't necessarily endorse cross-posting as I do find it frustrating as well. That's why it's very low on my scale of what to do.

Comment: In a broad sense, each site is considered a community, so "post to other communities" could be interpreted as "post to other [se] sites". Maybe rephrasing as "Post to external communities" or something like that will make your suggestion clearer.