# Where do I ask a question about the features of commercially available USB-C cables?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I had a question on that topic placed in Electrical Engineering, and it was closed because "off-topic". It took a while but I found information on the scope of that community, and I understand why the question was closed there.
But what *is* the right community to ask it?

I posted this question here because of the first answer in [What should I do if I cannot find the right community for my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316228/what-should-i-do-if-i-cannot-find-the-right-community-for-my-question).

However, instead of asking a meta-community, I would prefer to find the solution of my problem on my own, i.e. through a proper search across all communities, and then see where the hits are clustered.

Comment: What *did* you find? *[Consumer electronics questions](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/consumer-electronics-questions)*?

Comment: For your second question, see this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70333/237989

Comment: One question per ..question, please. Instead of having it get closed for lack of focus, I edited out the second question, but noticed that might have been your actual concern. However, as the previous comment points out, there is already such a question.

Comment: [hardwarerecs.se]?

Answer (score 1):

> Where do I ask a question about the features of commercially available USB-C cables?

You can try https://superuser.com. E.g., see
https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-c?tab=Votes and [USB Type C Power Delivery Profile - max length?](https://superuser.com/q/961176/116475)